# By reordering entries in structure Craft doesn't show up some entries on front-end using {% nav %} tag

Tags: structure

Sometimes I need to reorder or drop certain entry to different ancestor entry in control panel. By doing that I "lose" some entries on front end using `{% nav %}` tag. A behaviour is depended on how I reorder entries. Why?

```
{# We excluded the entry id which is ancestor of all entries in structure #}
{% set shop = craft.entries.section('shop').id('not 96') %}

{% nav page in shop %}
{% set slug = page.slug %}

   <li>

    <a href="{{ page.url }}">
      <span>
        {{ page.title }}
      </span>
    </a>

    {# Link description #}
    {% if lastSeg == page.slug %}
      <span>{{ description|ucfirst }}</span>
    {% endif %}

    {% ifchildren %}
      <ul class="hide{% if slug == secondSeg or slug == thirdSeg or slug == lastSeg %} show{% endif %}">
        {% children %}
      </ul>
    {% endifchildren %}

  </li>
{% endnav %}
```

**The structure section in control panel**

[image: The structure section in control panel]
**Not complete entries in front end**

[image: Entries in front end]